# Debian Jessie repositories and git

Tags: debian, git, apt-get, repository

How should I edit the sources.list so I will be able to get Git via apt-get?

If I run

```
apt-get install git
```

now, I get

> Unable to locate package git

While I can manually download and compile (I think) from http://packages.debian.org/jessie/git 
I would like to get it working with apt-get if possible.

I am using Debian testing Jessie.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please don't use tags in question titles. System has built-in support for tags and users are accustomed to them.

Comment: Try an `apt-get update` first. If that doesn't work, post your `sources.list`. Git should be installable without any special setup.